# Truncate helper on a link_to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, truncate

Is it possible to truncate a link_to within rails using the truncate helper of course, I have this link_to in my app

```
<%= link_to b.bookname, b %>
```

This is within a .each do so i am passing through b for example

messed around with a few variations but unable to get to work at present,

Anyone done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [truncate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate) helper

```
<%= link_to truncate(b.bookname, :length => 5), b %>
```

Comment: how do i pass the length though? :length => 30 for example, where does this go?