# To cut off the link in the comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

if the user inserted the link into the comment, this link needs to be cut off to 20 characters.

How to make it?

For example:

```
Lorem ipsum: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
```

It shall turn out so.

```
Lorem ipsum: https://github.com/plataforma...
```

Comment: You may want to check out [the `truncate` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286455/truncate-helper-on-a-link-to-rails) :)

Comment: @summea 
how to define, whether the user entered the link?

Comment: that is for you to decide... :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't present any code, so it's hard to say exactly how to do it for your code, but this generally is the approach you'd use:

```
<td>Comment:</td>
<td><%= @comment.text.length > 23 ? "#{@comment.text[0..20]}..." : @comment.text %></td>
```

Comment: I will try. Thanks.
I at first wanted to write a method which finds the reference through the regular expression and if the link is it to cut off.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer - general advice: assume ruby already has this function for you and go looking for it. Only if you do not find it, should you try to write it yourself. :)

Comment: I'm sure that you mean "Rails" in this case, unless you can point me to an actual Ruby function that does this.  It certainly isn't Excerpt since that's part of ActionView::Helpers

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails built in helper for this:

```
<td><%= excerpt(@comment.text, '', radius: 20) %></td>
```

or even better:

```
<td><%= truncate(@comment.text, length: 20) %></td>
```